# pgAdmin 4 shows the same table column twice

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Just started to use postgreSQL for the first time, so I am not very good at using its tools such as pgAdmin 4 etc, but there is one thing which either makes me thing is a bug or I am not able to understand the logic. So, every table had a serial id column, but at some point I decided to update them by setting those columns as Identity column instead. Everything worked fine, but as soon as I did the change after refreshing the page I see that columns are duplicated. Initially I thought that postgreSQL duplicated the columns, but that does not make sense from what I know for a table to have the two columns with the same name. Therefore I decided to open the same db in DataGrip from where I can see that the columns are not duplicated but they show as intended.

Here is the image from pgAdmin 4.

[image]

Here is the image from DataGrip.

[image]

Does anybody know if this might be a bug or something else that I dont understand about pgAdmin 4 ?

Comment: Which version of PgAdmin-4?

Comment: It is most likely a display format problem. That's one of the issues I have experienced with pgAdmin4 (that is one reason why I avoid it). Try closing completely down and reopening. That usually clears i up.  Good Luck.

Comment: I just finished fixing the same problem for myself and came across your post. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67230334/4923949 hope this helps