# Duplicate column after switching from serial to identity datatype in PostgreSQL / pgAdmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I was using the `serial` datatype to create a `PRIMARY KEY` column but was recently informed that this is outdated and I should be using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` instead. I used pgAdmin 4 to fix it by changing the datatype to integer and then adding the generated as identity. This worked but I am a bit baffled by the result as the SQL code shows 2 id columns instead of 1 now:

```
CREATE TABLE public.names
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    name character varying(128) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT names_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

However when I query the table with `SELECT * FROM names` it still shows me only 1 id column as there was before.

I would appreciate help on understanding what went wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps that is fallout from [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=19781729f789f3c6b2540e02b96f8aa500460322) bug. Are you using a recent minor release? You should report that as a bug to pgAdmin.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I', using pgAdmin version 5.1 with PostgreSQL 12.6. Do you have any idea how I can undo this?

Comment: No, since I don't know the query that pgAdmin uses to a) convert a serial column to an identity column and b) to generate that buggy output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lengthy search here is what I found:

There is indeed only one column which can be confirmed using psql. However using the command `pg_dump -st names <databasename>` from bash I noticed that there were 2 sequences being defined associated with the id column: `public.names_id_seq` and `public.names_id_seq1`.

This can also be confirmed by running `SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';` from psql where both sequences show up.

If one tries to delete `public.names_id_seq1` one gets the error `ERROR:  cannot drop sequence apis_id_seq1 because column id of table apis requires it`.

The **solution** is to delete the first sequence with `DROP SEQUENCE names_id_seq;` After refreshing pgAdmin4 the second column was gone.

**TL;DR**

1. Run `SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';` and identify duplicate sequences (ie. the ones where there is a version with and one without a 1 at the end)
2. Delete the superfluous sequence with `DROP SEQUENCE <sequenceName_seq>;` (only the one without a 1 at the end can be deleted)
3. Refresh pgAdmin4